# Using android media3 transformer to make color transparent

Tags: android, android-media3

I would like to set the opacity/transparency of a specified color in a video in android using media3 transformer.

I'm working with the demo app found here:
https://developer.android.com/media/media3/transformer/demo-application

The code to modify the video is below but I don't see anything in the documentation to modify the opacity of a color.

```
private ImmutableList<Effect> createVideoEffectsFromBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    boolean[] selectedEffects =
        bundle.getBooleanArray(ConfigurationActivity.VIDEO_EFFECTS_SELECTIONS);

    if (selectedEffects == null) {
      return ImmutableList.of();
    }

    ImmutableList.Builder<Effect> effects = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.DIZZY_CROP_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(MatrixTransformationFactory.createDizzyCropEffect());
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.EDGE_DETECTOR_INDEX]) {
      try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("androidx.media3.demo.transformer.MediaPipeShaderProgram");
        Constructor<?> constructor =
            clazz.getConstructor(
                Context.class,
                boolean.class,
                String.class,
                boolean.class,
                String.class,
                String.class);
        effects.add(
            (GlEffect)
                (Context context, boolean useHdr) -> {
                  try {
                    return (GlShaderProgram)
                        constructor.newInstance(
                            context,
                            useHdr,
                            /* graphName= */ "edge_detector_mediapipe_graph.binarypb",
                            /* isSingleFrameGraph= */ true,
                            /* inputStreamName= */ "input_video",
                            /* outputStreamName= */ "output_video");
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> showToast(R.string.no_media_pipe_error));
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load MediaPipeShaderProgram", e);
                  }
                });
      } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast(R.string.no_media_pipe_error);
      }
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.COLOR_FILTERS_INDEX]) {
      switch (bundle.getInt(ConfigurationActivity.COLOR_FILTER_SELECTION)) {
        case ConfigurationActivity.COLOR_FILTER_GRAYSCALE:
          effects.add(RgbFilter.createGrayscaleFilter());
          break;
        case ConfigurationActivity.COLOR_FILTER_INVERTED:
          effects.add(RgbFilter.createInvertedFilter());
          break;
        case ConfigurationActivity.COLOR_FILTER_SEPIA:
          // W3C Sepia RGBA matrix with sRGB as a target color space:
          // https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#sepiaEquivalent
          // The matrix is defined for the sRGB color space and the Transformer library
          // uses a linear RGB color space internally. Meaning this is only for demonstration
          // purposes and it does not display a correct sepia frame.
          float[] sepiaMatrix = {
            0.393f, 0.349f, 0.272f, 0, 0.769f, 0.686f, 0.534f, 0, 0.189f, 0.168f, 0.131f, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1
          };
          effects.add((RgbMatrix) (presentationTimeUs, useHdr) -> sepiaMatrix);
          break;
        default:
          throw new IllegalStateException(
              "Unexpected color filter "
                  + bundle.getInt(ConfigurationActivity.COLOR_FILTER_SELECTION));
      }
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.MAP_WHITE_TO_GREEN_LUT_INDEX]) {
      int length = 3;
      int[][][] mapWhiteToGreenLut = new int[length][length][length];
      int scale = 255 / (length - 1);
      for (int r = 0; r < length; r++) {
        for (int g = 0; g < length; g++) {
          for (int b = 0; b < length; b++) {
            mapWhiteToGreenLut[r][g][b] =
                Color.rgb(/* red= */ r * scale, /* green= */ g * scale, /* blue= */ b * scale);
          }
        }
      }
      mapWhiteToGreenLut[length - 1][length - 1][length - 1] = Color.GREEN;
      effects.add(SingleColorLut.createFromCube(mapWhiteToGreenLut));
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.RGB_ADJUSTMENTS_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(
          new RgbAdjustment.Builder()
              .setRedScale(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.RGB_ADJUSTMENT_RED_SCALE))
              .setGreenScale(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.RGB_ADJUSTMENT_GREEN_SCALE))
              .setBlueScale(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.RGB_ADJUSTMENT_BLUE_SCALE))
              .build());
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.HSL_ADJUSTMENT_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(
          new HslAdjustment.Builder()
              .adjustHue(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.HSL_ADJUSTMENTS_HUE))
              .adjustSaturation(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.HSL_ADJUSTMENTS_SATURATION))
              .adjustLightness(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.HSL_ADJUSTMENTS_LIGHTNESS))
              .build());
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.CONTRAST_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(new Contrast(bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.CONTRAST_VALUE)));
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.PERIODIC_VIGNETTE_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(
          (GlEffect)
              (Context context, boolean useHdr) ->
                  new PeriodicVignetteShaderProgram(
                      context,
                      useHdr,
                      bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.PERIODIC_VIGNETTE_CENTER_X),
                      bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.PERIODIC_VIGNETTE_CENTER_Y),
                      /* minInnerRadius= */ bundle.getFloat(
                          ConfigurationActivity.PERIODIC_VIGNETTE_INNER_RADIUS),
                      /* maxInnerRadius= */ bundle.getFloat(
                          ConfigurationActivity.PERIODIC_VIGNETTE_OUTER_RADIUS),
                      bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.PERIODIC_VIGNETTE_OUTER_RADIUS)));
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.SPIN_3D_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(MatrixTransformationFactory.createSpin3dEffect());
    }
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.ZOOM_IN_INDEX]) {
      effects.add(MatrixTransformationFactory.createZoomInTransition());
    }

    @Nullable OverlayEffect overlayEffect = createOverlayEffectFromBundle(bundle, selectedEffects);
    if (overlayEffect != null) {
      effects.add(overlayEffect);
    }

    float scaleX = bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.SCALE_X, /* defaultValue= */ 1);
    float scaleY = bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.SCALE_Y, /* defaultValue= */ 1);
    float rotateDegrees =
        bundle.getFloat(ConfigurationActivity.ROTATE_DEGREES, /* defaultValue= */ 0);
    if (scaleX != 1f || scaleY != 1f || rotateDegrees != 0f) {
      effects.add(
          new ScaleAndRotateTransformation.Builder()
              .setScale(scaleX, scaleY)
              .setRotationDegrees(rotateDegrees)
              .build());
    }

    int resolutionHeight =
        bundle.getInt(ConfigurationActivity.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, /* defaultValue= */ C.LENGTH_UNSET);
    if (resolutionHeight != C.LENGTH_UNSET) {
      effects.add(Presentation.createForHeight(resolutionHeight));
    }

    return effects.build();
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify opacity in on an overlay or video frame of a video file?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the video itself. I've been able to extract the frames and modify the transparency in javascript but not not in java/kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaCodec, used in Transformer to encode videos, strip out opacity. Therefore, transparency in media3 is only useful when you are overlaying things on top of each other, either by using multiple `EditedMediaItemSequence`s, or by using overlays like `BitmapOverlay`, or if you're choosing to use `VideoFrameProcessor` without using the rest of `Transformer`. Transformer would not be able to let you have non-1 opacity in an output video.

If you'd just like to set transparency on frames, before they're encoded, there's an `AlphaScale` effect that allows you to scale an entire frame's transparency, [here](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/libraries/effect/src/main/java/androidx/media3/effect/AlphaScale.java). If you'd like to scale just the opacity of a color, media3 doesn't currently have support for this. You could implement this by implementing your own `GlEffect` (and `GlShaderProgram`) instance, and injecting that into the list of effects to apply to a video. For a full list of `GlEffect`s, please see [this query](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aandroidx%2Fmedia+AND+%28%22implements+GlEffect%22+OR+%22extends+GlEffect%22+NOT+test%29&type=code).